# Mysql Variables not working through php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$query = " 

 SET @points := -1;
 SET @num := 0;

 SELECT `id`,`rank`,
 @num := if(@points = `rank`, @num, @num + 1) as `point_rank`
 FROM `said`
 ORDER BY `rank` *1 desc, `id` asc";
```

I'm using this query from php; giving me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @num := 0;

If I copy and paste that code in phpmyadmin Sql query panel, it works perfectly, but from the php code lines it's not working, seems like there's an issues while setting Vars.

Comment: Those are 3 queries and one execution. Does your DB library support multiple queries? If it doesn't, you'll need to split it in three.

Comment: the semi colons separating the queries !!

Comment: i've been using multiple queries through php, but i can see what you mean, the last query depends on the first ones.... any solution for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting the variables in a separate `SET`, have you tried using a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
$query = " 

SELECT `id`,
  `rank`,
  @num := if(@points = `rank`, @num, @num + 1) as `point_rank`
FROM `said`
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @points:=-1, @num:=0) c
ORDER BY `rank` *1 desc, `id` asc";
```

Comment: @Emad The nice thing about this is the variable are reset in the query instead of in a separate `set` statement.

Comment: This also worked from java when using a jdbc PreparedStatement. Good tip!

Comment: oh man for some reason my variables werent working with the other methods and this has literally retained my employment status! THANK YOU!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SET @points := -1 ;");
$result2 = mysql_query("SET @num := 0;");
$result3 = mysql_query($this->query); // <-- without the SET ... query
```

From the Manual:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)

EDIT:

You should use PDO or mysqli as mysql will soon deprecated .

Comment: @itachi you dont see he is taging `MYSQL` ?

Comment: the current code is :
$query1= $db->select("SET @points := -1;");
  $query2 = $db->select("SET @num := 0");
  $query = "SELECT `id`,`rank`,
     @num := if(@points = `rank`, @num, @num + 1) as `point_rank`
     FROM `said`   
     ORDER BY `rank` *1 desc, `id` asc";

Comment: @itachi means *"eww, the PHP ext-mysql library, which is now deprecated; ext-mysqli or PDO should be used instead."*

Comment: Hint: there are other apis for db which are NOT DEPRECATED . `MYSQL` != `mysql_*`