# MySQL query working in phpmyadmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

i've created a mysql view which is expecting 2 parameters and i'm able to query it without problems in phpyadmin with the following sql-string:

```
SET @date1 = '2014-02-06'; 
SET @date2 = '2014-02-07'; 
SELECT * FROM _myquery
```

it will not work under php - i'm getting the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @date2 = '2014-02-07'; SELECT * FROM _myquery' at line 2

when it's working in phpmyadmin, shouldn't it also work under php?
any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You can probably only run 1 statement at a time, you have 3.

Comment: As jeroen said, you can only run one at a time. But what's the point of setting variables you aren't using anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the MySQL variables? because your `SELECT` query is not using them.
You can try just with

```
SELECT * FROM _myquery
```

But if you really need to use MySQL variables, take a look at this:

[Mysql Variables not working through php mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742586/mysql-variables-not-working-through-php-mysql-query)

[MySql variables and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580700/mysql-variables-and-php)